# AWS EC2 docker machine with amazonec2 driver - Host already exists

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker-machine

The following command should create a new docker machine on a shiny new Amazon EC2 instance:

```
docker-machine \
      --storage-path /path/to/folder/docker_machines \
      create \
      --driver amazonec2 \
      --amazonec2-access-key <my key> \
      --amazonec2-secret-key <my secret> \
      --amazonec2-vpc-id <my vpc>  \
      --amazonec2-region <my region> \
      --amazonec2-zone <my AZ> \
      --amazonec2-security-group <existing Sec Grp> \
      --amazonec2-ami ami-da05a4a0 \
      --amazonec2-ssh-keypath /path/to/private/key \
     --engine-install-url=https://web.archive.org/web/20170623081500/https://get.docker.com \
     awesome-new-docker-machine
```

I ran this command once, and encountered a legitimate problem (bad path to private key). Once I fixed that and ran the command again, I get this error:

`Host already exists: "awesome-new-docker-machine"`

However, I can't find this docker machine anywhere:

```
$ docker-machine ls
NAME     ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER        ERRORS
```

I even tried a `docker-machine rm` and `docker-machine kill` just for giggles. No difference.

I can't see a new EC2 instance on Amazon having been created from the first, erroneous run of the command.

How can I "clean up" whatever's existing (somewhere) so I can recreate the machine correctly?

Comment: If you change the name to something other then "awesome-new-docker-machine" do you get the same error?

Comment: No. It initializes a new EC2 instance successfully. However, that doesn't help me find out what is left behind that it still finds from the first command run.

Comment: and if you run 'docker-machine rm -f awesome-new-docker-machine' what happens?

Comment: Error removing host "awesome-new-docker-machine": Host does not exist: "awesome-new-docker-machine"
Can't remove "awesome-new-docker-machine"

Comment: Also, now that I think about it, it maybe makes sense that `docker-machine` command run locally (e.g. `ls`, `rm`, `kill`) don't show a local docker machine instance, because there is none. It gets created in Amazon land, far far away. Sure, ideally I'd like my local session/host to "know" about that remote machine, since it was "created" locally... but I'm guessing that's asking for too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out that the first run of the command created some initial artifacts in a new folder `awesome-new-docker-machine` under `/path/to/folder/docker_machines`.

Deleting this folder and trying again worked perfectly.